# Spring MVC + Angular routing gives 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have created a Spring MVC project along with a client side angular app.

For the angular app,
Here is the content of ***/webapp/resources/js/app.js*** file

```
    'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
    'ngMaterial',
    'rzModule'

]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
      .when('/views/1', {
        controller: 'MyController',
        templateUrl: '/views/view1.html'
      })
      .when('/views/2', {
          controller: 'MyController',
          templateUrl: '/views/view2.html'
      })
      .when('/views/file-upload', {
          controller: 'MyController',
          templateUrl: '/views/file-upload.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
});
```

But the given templateUrls like ***"templateUrl: '/views/file-upload.html'"*** are seem to be not working.

The views are within ***/webapp/WEB-INF/views*** folder.

[image]

I want to know which addresses should I give inorder to route this views in app.js

Comment: Do you have a console errors? It may point to right direction.